# How to tell TypeORM to use different logger (pino in this case)?

Tags: node.js, logging, nestjs, typeorm, pinojs

I am using [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/), [TypeORM](https://typeorm.io/), [pino](https://github.com/pinojs/pino) and [nestjs-pino](https://github.com/iamolegga/nestjs-pino).

I need pino for my logs to be in JSON format, so that [Google Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging) can parse the logs.

However, TypeORM logs are not in JSON format. They still somehow use their own logger.

Is it possible to tell TypeORM to use the nestjs-pino logger instead of its own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have implemented a custom TypeORM logger using pino: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/logging.md#using-custom-logger

I have blatantly ripped of https://github.com/jtmthf/nestjs-pino-logger/issues/2#issuecomment-586163940 and https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/logger/SimpleConsoleLogger.ts.